# Apple Developers Program "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" - is empty

Tags: ios, certificate

After renewing the Developers account including the enterprise account we are faced with the following problem :
Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles - is empty
https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action

and while updating via xcode - catch error

> The selected team does not have a program membership that is eligible for this >feature.  If you need assistance, please contact Apple Developer Program >Support.
>   https://developer.apple.com/support

We ruled out browser issues or specific users issue. It's for all the team.

Any one met this before ?

Answer (score 72):

This same thing has happened to me twice now. There's a delay between the time that you renew your membership and when your account is activated. If you wait approximately 30 minutes from the time you renew your subscription, and refresh the ios certificate page on developer.apple.com, your certificate will magically show up.

I just went through this like an hour ago. It was sure be rad if apple would at least explain wtf is going on after you re-submit your yearly fee.

Comment: I waited about 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

I've come to this before, well I'd think anyone who has either just purchased a subscription of the developer program or in need to renew after paying for the new year.

To fix your problem you just need to follow the steps of [creating a certificate](http://youtu.be/HlRI30F6-Ek). Then once you have created a new certificate you **must** go to each **provisioning profile** and renew each one bc they will lost a **expired**. To fix this you just hit edit and select your new certificate.

I advice to create certificate on one machine then in Xcode export the profile to all other machines by going to **Xcode Preferences** > **Accounts** and clicking on your account then exporting. With a passcode is a good idea. Of course before exporting see if creating a certificate solved the issue :)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks ! But I mentioned Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles - is empty. So I can't access the certificates portal at all.....

We have now a new assumption that it might be because we paid both for regular and enterprise accounts... Will check it with their support as soon as the weekend is over.

Comment: Ooh, that's odd, so you can't get into the page with the certificates, provisioning profiles, etc page when you log in to developer.apple.com?

Comment: That is the case ..... We are stuck and so far Apple haven't solved it as well. But we are stuck !

Comment: That's too bad :( Now I am very curious on what you're seeing when trying to fix this yourselves :(

Comment: Same thing happened to me, unfortunately this answer was not helpful and really did not address the question

Comment: You just have to wait a few minutes